# How to use tf.einsum within Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Calling tf.einsum with Keras variables raises the following error:

> File
>   "/home/yotam/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/special_math_ops.py",
>   line 256, in _einsum_reduction
>       raise ValueError()
>
> ValueError

Running the same command using Tensorflow variables work as intended. This is surprising because other commands in tensorflow using Keras variables such as tf.matmul works properly. What is the difference and how to properly use tf.einsum?

Here is an example doing matrix multiplication using einsum (and for comparison also regular matmul) exemplifying the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K

n=4; k=3; T=2

a_tf = tf.placeholder(tfCHALLENGE.float32, shape=(n, T))
b_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(T, k))
output_tf = tf.einsum('ij,jk->ik',a_tf,b_tf) #WORKS

a_ker = K.variable(np.arange(n*T).reshape((n,T)), dtype='float32')
b_ker = K.variable(np.arange(T*k).reshape((T,k)), dtype='float32')
outputs_ker = tf.einsum('ij, jk->ik', a_ker, b_ker) #ValueError  
outputs_ker = tf.matmul(a_ker, b_ker) #WORKS
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to be more specific about "fail" and "works". Also the comments in your code suggest that both methods work, which is confusing.

Comment: Thanks, edited the post. matmul is a particular case of einsum, but einsum can do much more. The code shows that in this example matmul works, but the same command doing it using einsum doesn't work with keras vairables, but works with tensorflow variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Keras variables. The problem is the space you have in the second tf.einsum equation. Line 13 should be:

```
outputs_ker = tf.einsum('ij,jk->ik', a_ker, b_ker)
```